# Unable to load data in Data Binding Expression in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to angular JS. I'm using 1.5x stable version of js. I've started with a simple html code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>First JS demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    Name :
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />  {{ name }}

    <script src="angular.min.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But while rendering the html in browser im only getting {{ name }} text in data binding expression instead of the actual name value typed in the textbox. I checked that the JS file is loaded correctly in HTML.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not full code! Where is your controller and module?

Comment: I didn't write any controller. I was trying a pretty simple primitive example where I'm just binding the textbox data with a data property "name" and just showing it.

Answer (score 2):

You must be define app name and controller name

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>First JS demo</title>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name :
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />  {{ name }}

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped. Actually i was defining app name without a controller. Corrected it. Thanks :)